# How to import multiple things in javascript

Tags: javascript, redux, babeljs, redux-observable

I want to import multiple things in js, I have tried with `import *` like this:

the export file AppEpics.js:

```
export fooEpic = Observable.of() // some fancy code;
export barEpic = Observable.of() // some other fancy code;
```

the import file:

```
import * as App from './AppEpics'
export default combineEpics(...App)
```

I found that while I log the `App`, I get a object that contains the foo and bar, but when I log the `...App`, I get nothing.

I am using babel preset env and react for now. How do I solve that?

BTW, the combineEpics only accepts the epics like `fooEpics`, so that I cannot call this function like this:

```
import * as App from './AppEpics'
export default combineEpics(App) // that will not work.
```

Comment: Why not use `import { foo, bar } from './App'`?

Comment: App is a single object, not a collection. The spread operator is confused. Should simply be `combineEpics(App);` The combineEpics() function accesses `App.foo` and `App.bar`

Comment: Because I will import tons of things, and that will make a lot of mistakes.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Actually, I am using redux-observable right now, the combineEpics is a function of redux-observable. so that I cannot modify the combineEpics.

Comment: Of course. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `App` is object in your case and you try to spread it as arguments for function `combineEpics(...App)` which would work only if App is array.

If you want to pass all the exported values into `combineEpics` you need to do smth like `combineEpics(...Object.values(App))` or add `export default [foo, bar]` in App.js and `import App from './App' and combineEpics(...App)` in file.

Comment: I can spread the rest properties with this plugin: http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/. Why I cannot spread the whole properties of an object?

Comment: You definitely can, but only into another object, e.g. `f = { ...App }` not into function call as in `combineEpics(...App)` which is only for arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Remove "as App" from your import:

```
import * from './App'
```

It should work.

Comment: But how can I add all of these foobar into the combineEpics. it seems that I still have to add them one by one manually.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to import all at once you also can use

```
import * from './yourName'
```

in case you want to import specific components to a file

```
import { Comp1, Comp2, Comp3 } from './yourName'
```

It´s needed to export your components. You can do that also at once. For that i added a default reference to a file (index.js) within my package.json.

```
  "name": "yourName",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
```

Within the index.js i added the exports.

```
 export { default as Comp1 } from './yourPath/comp1'
```